# Can mutli-threading java client cause high CPU utilization of SQL Server 2008?

Tags: java, multithreading, sql-server-2008, cpu-usage, database-performance

I am a Java Developer, not a DBA, and would like to consult about an issue encountered in **high CPU utilization in the SQL Server 2008** *(not in the Java app server)*.

The Java client uses multi-threading, to simplify:

1. 40 threads each select / insert / update (simple SQL statements) from Table X - autocommit is ON
2. 10 threads each select / insert / update (simple SQL statements) from Table Y and selects (again simple)  from Table X (to check for existence) - autocommit is ON

Both set of threadpools run simultaneously. Each thread is assigned to "message from a queue" (a file), loads / reads its assigned "message", and inserts / updates to its corresponding table. These 2 thread pools get connections from a single connection pool via datasouce, for example:

```
    <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" maxActive="100" maxIdle="10" maxWait="10000" name="jdbc/abc_DataSource" password="p" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:sqlserver://NTxxx\\instyyy:12345;databaseName=dbzzz" username="u"/>
```

The DB environment is SQL Server 2008 R2 and is shared by other apps, but the Java client above was flagged to be the causing the CPU utilization. When the Java client was shutdown, the utilization stabilized. From the Java client's application server Jboss, the statistics where the Java was running does not have any performance issues, CPU and memory are fine; it was only the DB Server that got its CPU spiked.

My question is, does the high amount of threads, which will consume the datasource's pool of maxActive 100, **potentially be the cause?** If so, **how can I prove this** from the DB perspective, ie. SQL server statistics pointing to the high volumne threads from Java client?

Posted also in DBA stack, but not getting any views...:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/96502

Comment: Please show us `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and samples of the statements.  Also, what value is being used for autocommit?  And, do you wrap the statements in `BEGIN...COMMIT`?

Answer (score 1):

Your description is too generic to give a detailed answer. Nevertheless, even simple statements can cause substantial database activity, if the database has either plenty of values or no matching indexes and needs to fall back to full table scans for each select.

So, my first suggestion is, that you use the SQL studio application with the activity analyzer. There you will find the current load on the machine and, more important, a list of "currently valuable queries". Those list queries, that are most responsible for the current CPU load. You will see queries that are executed very often, but only take very little time per execution and you will see queries that are executed only few times, but are extremely expensive to execute.

You can then evaluate the queries from your java application and get optimization hints. Very helpful.

The other point is, if the queries cannot be optimized, maybe the data inserted is expensive to handle (for example BLOB objects) or the sql server is not powerful enough to handle the amount of rows with the amount of memory and the other applications running at the same time.

If you cannot solve the issue on the query side, you may need to inspect your code, if you can throttle the DB load by implementing a queueing mechanism in between or if you need to implement a caching layer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply about how to monitor, however I need the statistics that prove that it is due to the multi-threading nature of the application (100 simultaneous database hits for 40k records in table X and 40k in table Y in intervals). Do you have any idea how to show this in the monitor?

Comment: If you really fire with all 40+10 threads to your SQL server, the sql server is likely to get a hit. Regarding your stats: Just half the amount of threads and see what happens. If you already overload the SQL server, you will likely see a higher performance with less threads. Also, if possible, you should always batch insert large amounts of data. The reason is simply that you can avoid costly index updates between inserts. In the activity monitor, application threads are unknown. You need to derive the load from the wait, IO, valuable queries.

Answer (score 0):

The number of thread seems to high since database has to serialize request At some point vince data area anyway on a disk. I suspect the high loda is cause by the enormous amount of roundtrip you area doping with the dB server. Try to pack the requests in orde to minimize roundtrips, and drastically reduce the threads count.Bad indexes on the queries could be an issue too, but in this case eden the disk would be overloaaded.

Comment: I agree with you that the thread is too high. However, how can I prove it with facts? For example, how can I get this information from the DB server  ? The reason why I need to get the stats is so I can convince our team that we need to use a bulk insert/update approach instead of a multi-threaded approach.